# Server side automation testing using Java and JSON requests

Tags: java, testing, automation, automated-tests

I have not done automation testing before, only jUnit testing, now I have a request to do that. But the automation is not on frontend using Selenium or so, it is simpler than that, using JSONs requests. I understand the principles of that, but don't know how to do it programmatically correct. I have to do some payment request to the server and see if the response is correct, not just the code, but the details of response as well.

So far I have done the part with request to the server, now when I receive the response, what is the best way to compare or to check it, or how I can see if everything is right? can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: It *sounds* like you are trying to automate functional testing of a RESTful API (e.g. given your comparison to Selenium).  If so, take a look at SoapUI if you have not already considered it.  It can send static or parameterized requests and check every detail of responses with little or no scripting; and if you have more complex needs, you can script it like mad in Groovy.  You could also use a testing framework like you would typically use for unit or integration tests (e.g. JUnit), but I find SoapUI much better for this sort of thing.

Comment: SoapUI is an app, but I do need to do this tests for the whole team, so an app would be a great idea for a solo or one time testing, but our API will grow and all the people should be able to add/modify the functionality. Anyway thanks for that.

Comment: Yes, I have done just that with the open-source version of SoapUI - across thousands of functional tests. SoapUI may not be/end up the tool you prefer, but it is plenty capable of such testing for your whole team and working with continuous integration; and as a Java developer, you actually have a leg up that I have never had as a .NET developer - first-class IDE integration (for IntelliJ IDEA, Eclipse, and NetBeans).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding your requirement correctly, then:

1. First check what is the format of request and response.
2. As you said its JSON, you can easily do this using JAVA. Use java package - org.json.JSONObject to create request and validate JSON format.
3. You can send request and get response by this simple code:

   ```
           CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
           HttpGet GetRequest = new HttpGet("ServerURL");
           CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(GetRequest);
   ```

   use packages: import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;

   you may need to download apache - httpClient jar also.
4. Once you have the response, read it using some reader, like:

   ```
   BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader( new  InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
   ```
5. Convert this response into a string like:

   ```
       String line = "";
       StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
       while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
       {
           result.append(line);
       }
   ```
6. Finally you have the string response, this can be further analysed by using java package - org.json.JSONObject. Analyse the JSON response like:

   ```
   JSONObject js = new JSONObject(hudsonRTBObjectJSONString);
   ```

Hope this helps

Comment: Ok, this is only a part of it that I can hadle, but I was meaning the validation of the response, to understand better: if the payment was ok or not.